# How to get data-id value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I didn't find an answer to my question in previous threads...so I have to ask.

I have a table with latest column with action button, the td tag include a data-id reference as follows:

```
<td data-id="1">
    <div class="btn-group dropdown">
        <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="table-action-btn dropdown-toggle arrow-none btn btn-light btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-dots-horizontal"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil mr-2 text-muted font-18 vertical-middle"></i>Edit</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item history" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-check-all mr-2 text-muted font-18 vertical-middle"></i>AC history</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item remove" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-delete mr-2 text-muted font-18 vertical-middle"></i>Remove</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-star mr-2 font-18 text-muted vertical-middle"></i>Mark as Unread</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Using the following javascript code I'm trying to get the data-id attribute when the user click on the dropdown menu. I'd liket o to use the class into the i tag...without adding any extras class or tag

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click",".mdi-pencil",function(){
            
       var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent("td").data('id');
    
       console.log('ID is ' + id);
    });
 });
```

The code doesn't work and I cannot even get the console.log feedback in Chrome console. I can easily add an extra class into the a href tag and doing so the code work...but as I wrote above I'd like to avoid extras classes.

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Check whether the function is invoked on click using console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is **data-id** is a attribute after all , so you can always get an attributes data with **attr()** in **jQuery**,
Although to reduce our coding and make it more efficient we can use directly **data()** function , as above people have answered .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
     alert($("p").attr('data-id'));

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-id = "100">paragraph </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to achieve it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $(".dropdown-item").on("click", function(){
 
   var td = $(this).closest("td");
   var id = $(td).data('id');
   console.log('ID is ' + id);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td data-id="1">
    <div class="btn-group dropdown">
        <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="table-action-btn dropdown-toggle arrow-none btn btn-light btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-dots-horizontal"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil mr-2 text-muted font-18 vertical-middle"></i>Edit</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item history" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-check-all mr-2 text-muted font-18 vertical-middle"></i>AC history</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item remove" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-delete mr-2 text-muted font-18 vertical-middle"></i>Remove</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-star mr-2 font-18 text-muted vertical-middle"></i>Mark as Unread</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for feedback and hint Phong. Weird...I've had to edit a bit the code since the above doesn't work...instead using the following runs smoothly...honestly I don't know why:$("body").on("click",".dropdown-item",function(){
     var td = $(this).closest("td");
     var id = $(td).data('id');
     console.log('The closest ID is ' + id);
    });

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it help you:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".dropdown-item").on("click", function() {
     $(this).parents('td').data('id');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).parents('td').data('id');
```

Comment: The question is asking about `data-id=""`, not `id=""`